# Dropdown list css styling for mobile media query

Tags: css, html, select, menu

Im trying to style my dropdown list for a site mobile navigation and it looks boring with the default down arrow. I'm just wondering how to replace the default arrow to the graphic i created.

```
<select name="mobilenav" id="mobilenav" title="Select Destination">
<option selected>Select Destination</option>
<option>Philadelphia</option>
<option>United States of America</option>
<option>Destination</option>
<option>Long Destination Names</option>
<option>Australia</option>
</select>
```

Also when i test it and tap the dropdown using my mobile device, it creates a pop up menu list instead of a dropdown menu.

Sorry for my ignorance and thanks in advance!

Comment: You should provide more information, like what css/ js code or library you are already using to style the dropdown and what browsers you are using for testing.

Answer (score 0):

The default select element can vary per device, IOS may look different than android. You may want to use a jQuery plug-in such as http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/ (or find one you like better) to change the default appearance. I'm not 100% sure if that will work on mobile, but should give you more style options for desktop browsers.

If you don't NEED to use a select element you could also use an unordered list, style it how ever you like, and use jQuery to expand and contract the list items on click... just a thought, not sure if thats an option for this case.